# Pegar valor de atributo personalizado "data-attribute" dentro de um loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero selecionar todos os atributos personalizados e fazer uma validação com eles, só que não sei como posso pega o valor do "attr" dentro de um loop, já que são eles que estão sendo iterados.

Exemplo HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-selected="teste" value="fulano" name="nome">
<input type="text" data-selected="teste2" value="de tal" name="sobrenome">
```

Exemplo:

```
$('[data-selected]').each(function(){

       alert( $(this).attr() ); // -> teste / teste2
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode fazer uso da API [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)<sup><sup>[(ver suporte no "Can I use")](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset)</sup></sup> para obter os *data-attributes* de um elemento específico:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-selected]')].map(element => {
  alert(element.dataset.selected)
})
```

```html
<div data-selected="teste"></div>
<div data-selected="teste2"></div>
```

Se realmente tiver a necessidade de utilizar jQuery, existe a função [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) que pode ser utilizada especificando o nome do atributo:

```js
$(function(){
  $('[data-selected]').each(function(){
       alert( $(this).data('selected') );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-selected="teste"></div>
<div data-selected="teste2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) O *seletor* deve ser assim: `input[data-selected]`. O que vai *buscar* os *inputs* que tenham o atributo *data-selected* definidos.

> Fonte: [API jQuery - Has Attribute Selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

2) Para *receber* o valor do atributo, deve informá-lo no método `.attr()`, como sugere a documentação do *jQuery*. Então, deve ficar assim: `$(this).attr('data-selected');`.

> Fonte: [API jQuery - .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

**Finalmente**, seu código ficaria assim:

```js
$('input[data-selected]').each(function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('data-selected') ); // -> teste / teste2
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-selected="teste" value="fulano" name="nome">
<input type="text" data-selected="teste2" value="de tal" name="sobrenome">
```

Comment: Uma explicaçao da resposta seria muito bem vinda! ;)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não se limita somente ao input, pode ser select etc também

Comment: Lógico. Basta informar o elemento-alvo no seletor do jQuery! @ArticunoL Feito!

Comment: Por que não só $(['data-selected'])?

Comment: Dá certo tb. Mas quando vc define o seletor nos `input` previne buscar outros "possíveis elementos" que talvez não sejam desejados...